# How to upload a file to node.js server folder without using a form or input file using ajax?

Tags: node.js, ajax, file-upload

I was trying to record and send .wav file from client to my node.js server folder. I get .wav file's link and  to display it on clients browser. i wanted to upload  the .wav file to server without  by using ajax.
I am using node.js and express.

I tried to send the url of my audio something like this (http://localhost:3000/b10cef8d-24ba-4503-b96c-92ebd23fc4a5), and try to copy the file to server folder.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
    aLink: audioLink    }),   //audioLink is link to my recorded audio on clients side
    success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);}
})
```

SERVER SIDE

```
    app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var alink = req.body.name;


    if (Object.keys(alink).length == 0) {
        return res.status(400).send('Audio is not submitted');
    }

    // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
    let sampleFile = alink;

    // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
    sampleFile.mv(path.join(__dirname ,'audios/test123.wav'), function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);

        res.send('File uploaded!');
    });

})
```

I expect the .wav file to be stored in my /audios folder.

Comment: There's no point in sharing a localhost URL, we cannot access your local server.

Comment: Have a look at FormData to upload files with javascript.

Comment: thanks for your response.so, how can I send the file to my server from the link i have?